# How can I install UNetbootin

Tags: unetbootin

I have Ubuntu-9.04 and I would like to install a newer release. Some people have suggested that I install UNetbootin to do this. However, when I download it , I get a .exe file and Ubuntu will not run such files.
How can I install UNetBootin?

Comment: Ubuntu 9.04 is EOL release.

Answer (score 2):

The [UNetbootin Homepage](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) features 3 big buttons on the top of the page. Click on the one with the penguin on it and you will receive a executable file. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. Navigate with `cd <folder-where-you-downloaded-the-file>` to the folder. Mark the file as executable

```
sudo chmod +x unetbootin-linux-585
```

Start unetbootin

```
./unetbootin-linux-585
```

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the UNetbootin [website](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), you can download it for Linux.  Once downloaded right click on the file, go to Properties --> Permissions tab and check Allow excuting file as a program, then start the application.

[image]

[image]

Also you can try [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/YUMI/ubuntu/yumi_0.0.1-1_all.deb) for Ubuntu.  Once you download Yumi, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to where the file was downloaded (Probably the Downloads Folder), and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <file_name>.deb
```

Comment: superb you are great

Answer (score 1):

if you want to install in direct GUI way then click here

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 0):

the .exe file you downloaded is the windows version of UNetbootin.
You can find UNetbootin in the Ubuntu software center or you can download it [here](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Under the link you have to select the debian version and just start that. Click install and there you have it. You've succesfully installed UNetbootin for linux.

The third method of installing UNetbootin for linux is typing the following commands.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

and then just start unetbootin from the dash or by typing unetbootin in a terminal.

Comment: thank you,but I've Ubuntu-9.04 version so where is ubuntu software center in it

Comment: I see, ubuntu-9.04 didn't have Unetbootin in it's repositories.
I've edited my answer to reflect this and add the repository needed.